# To show iPad's view on Macbook

Tags: ipad, macbook-pro, video, recording

This [tutorial](http://www.apptamin.com/blog/capture-iphone-ipad-screen-video/) raised a question if you can mirrow the screen of iPad Air through a cable to the newest Macbook Air.

So I think the cable should be something

- the power cable of iPad air To Lightning place of Macbook air

**Does there exist any such cable by which you can show the picture of your iPad on your Macbook Air?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it's not possible with a cable, but it will be possible in Yosemite by using your charging cable and QuickTime. (record your screen)

For now you can use [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/), this doesn't even require a cable. (mirror and record your screen)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have time to wait for Yosemite! :)

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer as the best answer, now I have enough reputation to comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, Apple provides no official way of doing this.

If you really need to, you could use Option 3 listed in the tutorial you linked to, the Apple Digital AV Adapter, combined with some sort of external video capture device for you Mac like the [Elgato Game Capture HD Game Recorder](http://store.apple.com/ca/product/H9452LL/A/elgato-game-capture-hd-game-recorder?fnode=61).